# Открытые сокеты Win

Tags: winapi, сокет

День добрый, задача такова получить открытые приложением сокеты(адрес\порт). 
Приложение не мое(мониторинг некоторых процесов), возможно ли?(если да то желательно апи функции или способы оного). в гугле не забанен, но как гуглить не представляю.

Comment: ps нужен только адрес, и порт, данные которые ходят мониторить нет необходимости.

Comment: netstat -a Но там, кажется, не всё. Только установленные tcp-соединения и порты, которые кто-то слушает.

Comment: эмм... открыть консоль вызвать нэт стат считать в буфер, закрыть.. не то немного вроде) есть приложение(написаное не мной) есть его PID(и открытый хэндл на чтение запись в память), необходимо получить открытые только этим приложением сокеты.
Открытые активные (нелокальные, хотя это вроде неважно) сокеты, открытые конкретным процессом. желательно быстродействие повыше чем вариант с нэтстатом.

Comment: хм, пока что проверил нэт стат ловит нужное мне подключение с такими параметрами :

    >netstat -n -b -p tcp

А теперь бы в разрезе одного приложения и апи функцией винды.

Comment: В unix есть очень полезная утилита - **lsof**.

Я очень быстро нагуглил для винды (искал: lsof windows)

    TCPView
    http://www.microsoft.com/technet/sysinternals/Networking/TcpView.mspx

Думаю Вы сможете найти что-то еше.

Comment: Спасибо за инфо) там по данному вопросу пара дополнений, пока что решал не мудрить с апи а пойти по накатаной,найти адреса и ссылки на открытые соединения в памяти самого процесса... т.к. мониторить придется одно и то же приложение, то вариант неплох.

Comment: Вариант - подгружать в нужные процессы либу, которая хукает функции WinSock. Советую посмотреть в сторону исходников программы L2PacketHack: http://coderx.ru